# wc command counts extra characters

Tags: linux, osx, wc

```
cat > file
Amy looked at her watch. He was late. The sun was setting but Jake didn’t care.

wc file
1      16      82 file
```

Can somebody explain why `wc` command returns 3 extra characters in this case?

Comment: I don't know.Typing that sentence, followed by a NL & Ctrl-D for me renders  **wc file
 1 16 80 file**  What environment are you in?

Comment: Because you have 3 spaces at the end of the line? Do `od -c file` to see exactly what is in there.

Comment: Use `wc -m` to count characters. `wc` and `wc -c` give a byte count, not a character count.

Answer (score 35):

`wc` shows 3 characters more because your example file contains a fancy Unicode apostrophe `’` (most likely because you copied the contents from a browser or text editor):

```
$ cat file
Amy looked at her watch. He was late. The sun was setting but Jake didn’t care.
$ wc file
1      16      82 file
```

With plain ASCII apostrophe `'`:

```
$ cat file2
Amy looked at her watch. He was late. The sun was setting but Jake didn't care.
$ wc file
1      16      80 file2
```

`wc` by default displays the number of bytes <sup>per [manual](http://linux.die.net/man/1/wc)</sup> :

> newline, word, and byte counts for each file

for character count an `-m` argument can be used:

```
$ cat file
Amy looked at her watch. He was late. The sun was setting but Jake didn’t care.
$ wc -m file
      80 file.txt
```

Comment: Yes, and because `wc` is counting *bytes*, not *characters*. http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/utilities/wc.html

Comment: Use `wc -m` to count characters,  `wc -c` and the 3rd column in `wc` output count bytes, not characters.

Answer (score 11):

pipe the file thrught `xxd` to see a hex output side-by-side of the ascii, this will let you see if there are extra characters which you can't see or are unprintable.

```
$ cat file
one‏ and ‏two

$ cat file | wc
      1       3      18

$ cat file | xxd
00000000: 6f6e 65e2 808f 2061 6e64 20e2 808f 7477  one... and ...tw
00000010: 6f0a                                     o.
```

Answer (score 2):

`wc` counts bytes, not characters. If you want to count characters, you should use [`-m` option](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/wc.1.html):

```
cat > file
Amy looked at her watch. He was late. The sun was setting but Jake didn’t care.

wc -l -w -m file
1      16      80 file
```

The remaining "extra character" is indeed the newline you have at the end of the file.